# Is JDK JAXB implemetation 100% matches XFIRE JAXB implementation

Tags: jaxb, xfire

I have a maven project in which I am using Xfire.

Now recently i came to know that JDK 1.6 has JAXB implementation included. But when compared Xfire JAXB classes from JDK classes nothing matches.

Can anybody tell me if I remove the JAXB mplementation dependency from code will anything bad can happen or if some packages are not yet implemented in jDk package which are present in Xfire JAXB implemetation.?

Answer (score 0):

[**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) is a standard that supports multiple implementations: [EclipseLink MOXy](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php), Metro, Apache JaxMe, etc, so XFire is free to include there own implementation.  As they depend on extensions in the JAXB implementation they include I would not recommend removing it.

Ultimately this question should be asked on the XFire mailing list:

- http://xfire.codehaus.org/Support